# Am I writing this email correctly?

Tags: interviewing, email

So he said two software developers will be interviewing me and he asked me for "a couple times that may work for you this week or next week" for a second interview, but I am stuck on my sentences and the expression of my availability. Please help me to fix this email, thanks.

Hi xx,

Thank you for the opportunity to be further considered for the Co-op (Software Developer - Banking Team) position. I look forward to meeting with your expert software developer team members.

I am available on Friday between 12pm and 5pm, and Monday to Saturday 9am to 5pm next week. Please let me know what time works best for you.

Kind regards,

xxx

Comment: Are Saturdays a normal working day in your potential employer's location?

Comment: I had employers did interviews on Saturday.

Comment: I would suggest not putting kisses (xxx) at the bottom of the message. - joking, I assume that's a placeholder for your name

Comment: In what country are you located in? In any case, if you don't have a job right now and can easily do an interview during business hours, do not mention Saturday. Saturday is only to be used if there is no other option for the candidate in question.

Comment: It's in Canada, and I am not a native English speaker, that's what I am asking. The details of the sentences.

Comment: Thanks, I just changed Saturday to Friday.

Answer (score 1):

**Give them some more specific options.**

I get the desire to be open, but one of the things that is often helpful is it give specific times, which allows the person responding to just say yes or no rather than call a bunch of people and try to come to a consensus time. They can just say "be there are 9:30."

I usually add a line like "How does 9:30 AM next Tuesday or Wednesday work for you?" A bit of this is a psychological attempt to nudge myself into a better position. I don't want to interview when lunch is on people's minds or when they are tired. I am also someone who is freshest at that time.

Most of the time, my suggested time is accepted.

Comment: Keep that edge, but consider the most optimal time for yourself as well for them. If one party was open-ended then it serves no purpose to be vague in your response, employers are looking for decision making skills, responding with specific times is the optimal response and with short circuit the traditional social back and forth to arrive at a time. This is business, subconsciously they want to see what decisions you can make with limited information.

Answer (score 0):

- only offer days that are really close to today
- do not offer weekend days
- **you absolutely must keep it short - this is the norm in business English**

Here's what I personally would write, I'd hit reply and

> Steve, thank you so much, what about Friday 2-4 or Monday 9-12. Would either of those be possible?  Thanks so much, Fattie!

I agree strongly with what Uncle Matthew says, **don't state long time slots**, however I feel a slot of 2-3 hours is good.

GOOD LUCK!

Answer (score 0):

"I am available on Friday between 12pm and 5pm, and Monday to Saturday 9am to 5pm next week. Please let me know what time works best for you."

Change to:

```
Following is my available time window:
Friday: 12:00 - 17:00
Monday to Saturday: 09:00 - 17:00
```

This would more clear. However, I think you may first time interview. Because I am very confidence to tell you, your writing is not bad, they don't care what you write at this stage. They only care if you continue or not, and provide time window or not.